# Full Text Search in interaction with index that has other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, full-text-search

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Id, int
FirstName, nvarchar
LastName, nvarchar
Description, ntext
```

I have a Full Text Catalog covering the **Description** field.

My query:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
WHERE LastName = 'Johnson'
AND CONTAINS(Description, 'house')
```

Now I'm wondering which index to use to optimize this query in order to be able to take full advantage of the Full Text Catalog. Would SQL Server be able to take advantage of an index on LastName in this case?

(I know I could just test it, but my real table and query structure is obviously not as simple as the above, so I'd rather know from someone who actually knows how it's supposed to work)

Comment: Full Text Search functionality only uses Full Text indexes: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/

Comment: I read the whole article. As far as I can see, he doesn't touch the subject of how the full text index is used in conjunction with an ordinary index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an index on `LastName` will help. SQL Server may create a plan that does basically a join between a range scan on the NC index for 'Johnson' and the result of the full text index search. This whitepaper contains some details that are of interest to you: [SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Queries on Large Catalogs: Lessons Learned](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917695.aspx).

Comment: You are correct that the article contains details of interest to me, although it seems they do not directly describe the scenario of this question.

Comment: As I understand your answer, SQL Server may do something like the following: 1. Find IDs of rows based on the Full Text Index 2. Find IDs of rows based on the normal index 3. Return rows that exist in both.